# Expire rows at the end of the day with Eloquent and Carbon in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have a job which should close at the end of the date specified in an `expires_on` column.

So if the expiry is 05/11/2018 the job should expire at 11:59 on that date.

My current query is this:

```
$job_posts = JobPost::where('expires_on', '<', Carbon::now())
    ->where('status', '<>', 'Closed')
    ->get();
```

However, this query closes the job at midnight (00:00) as this is effectively the start of that day, I would rather it close at the end of the date specified, not the beginning.

Would it be more correct to do this:

```
$job_posts = JobPost::where('expires_on', '<', Carbon::now())
    ->addDay(1))
    ->where('status', '<>', 'Closed')
    ->get();
```

Or this:

```
$job_posts = JobPost::where('expires_on', '<', Carbon::now())
    ->endOfDay())
    ->where('status', '<>', 'Closed')
    ->get();
```

**Update**

I changed the field expires_on to be a `datetime` field and in my model that refers to job posts I created a mutator that always sets the closing time to 23:59:59, like so:

```
/**
 * Set the expiry date to always be 11:59PM on the given day
 *
 * @param string $value
 * @return void
 */
public function setExpiresOnAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['expires_on'] = Carbon::parse($value)->endOfDay();
}
```

This means my original code, should, in theory do the job, as job expiry times are no longer midnight (00:00:00)

Comment: So why don't you modify the `Carbon::now()` by adding time `11:59`? Or check if the time is less than `Carbon::tomorrow()`?

Comment: Yep he could simply just modify the time

Comment: In your initial line of code you call `where` on the return from `Carbon::now()` which seems a bit strange and I don't remember **Carbon** having a `where` function supporting those arguments.

Comment: Thinking about it, could I not have just used <=

Answer (score 3):

Check if the date is less than the "tomorrow":

```
$job_posts = JobPost::where('expires_on','<', Carbon::tomorrow())
    ->where('status', '<>', 'Closed')
    ->get();
```

Less than tomorrow is, in fact, last second and less of the yesterday. Which is exactly the same as your two last examples.

Comment: You have the same issue with calling `where` on the return of `Carbon::tomorrow()` as the OP. I don't think this is what you want to do. At least I can't remember `Carbon` having such a function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeFromTimeString` function to add the specified time to `now`:

See the result of the function:

```
dd([Carbon::now(), Carbon::now()->setTimeFromTimeString("23:59")]);
```

Output is:

```
Carbon @1541421688 {#1418 ▼
  date: 2018-11-05 16:11:28.810618 Asia/Tehran (+03:30)
}
Carbon @1541449740 {#1420 ▼
  date: 2018-11-05 23:59:00.0 Asia/Tehran (+03:30)
}
```

So, In your query, you can use that function as below:

```
$job_posts = JobPost::where('expires_on', '<', Carbon::now()->setTimeFromTimeString("23:59"))
    ->where('status', '<>', 'Closed')
    ->get();
```